# Python, gae, ndb - get all keys in a kind

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I know how to get all entities by a key using `Book.get_by_id(key)`
where `Book` is an `ndb.Model`.

How do I get all the keys within my Kind?
Is it using `fetch()`(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_fetch) ?

- I don't want to get the keys/IDs from a given entity or some value. Just retrieve all the available keys, so I could retrieve their respectful entities and display it all to the user

Comment: From my experience, I would not recommend the approach of "fetch all" unless you can control the amount of entities in for a kind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `all_books = Book.query().fetch()` the `all_books` variable will now have every entity of your `Book` model.

Note though that when you have lots of entities in the `Book` model - it won't be a good idea to load&show them all at once. You will need some kind of pagination implementation (depending on what exactly you're doing) - otherwise your pages will load forever which will create a bad experience for your users.

Read more at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries

Comment: `Book.query()` is actually enough. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @PyGAE actually, `Book.query()` is a query.  It just happens to behave like a list when you iterate over it.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass

Answer (score 6):

If you only want the keys, use the `keys_only` keyword in the `fetch()` method:

```
Book.query().fetch(keys_only=True)
```

Then you can fetch all the entities using `ndb.get_multi(keys)`.  [According to Guido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596869/is-it-best-to-query-by-keys-only-true-then-get-multi-or-just-full-query), this may be more efficient than returning the entities in the query (if the entities are already in the cache).

Answer (score 1):

If you only wish to get all keys just use

`entity.query().fetch(key_only=True)`

which will return a list of all keys in that entity group. If you wanna get the IDs and not keys you can also use:

`map(lambda key: key.id(), entity.query().fetch(key_only=True))`

Comment: as of 2022 `key_only=True` seem not to work anymore. Raising following exception: `TypeError: QueryOptions got an unexpected keyword argument 'key_only'`